# Unmelt a dataframe by column data values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below.(df1)

```
name,Measure,Value
gift,cost,20
gift,Factor,0.2
newsletter,cost,15
newsletter,Factor,0.05
seminar,cost,23
seminar,Factor,0.3
```

I need to be converted to dataframe df2.

```
name  cost  factor
gift    20    0.20
newsletter    15    0.05
seminar    23    0.30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `pd.DataFrame.pivot`:

```
df.pivot(index='name',columns='Measure', values='Value').rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           Factor  cost
name                    
gift          0.20  20.0
newsletter    0.05  15.0
seminar       0.30  23.0
```